# CSS+Bootstrap: track CSS property in Prestashop wizard

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, smarty, prestashop

I'm just customizing Prestashop to use it in Right-to-Left format. I should add that I have no understanding of Bootstrap.
In one of wizard forms in Shipping--> Carrier Wizard section of Prestashop, I have problem with a CSS property and I cannot track where this property applied to fix it or disable it.

---

Here is the details:
[image]

It can be seen the form is shifted too much to left.
I used firebug to investigate the issue. Here is the firebug output:
[image]

As you can see this is because of `right: 1124px;` property in `DIV` with `id='step-1'`. But checking the source of this feature I could not find the related css file in FireBug.But disabling right property will fix the problem.[image]
What I want to know is where this property applied and how it can be changed?
I also found the related `.tpl` file of this wizard which brought here:

```
{extends file="helpers/view/view.tpl"}
{block name="override_tpl"}
<script>
    var labelNext = '{$labels.next|addslashes}';
    var labelPrevious = '{$labels.previous|addslashes}';
    var labelFinish = '{$labels.finish|addslashes}';
    var labelDelete = '{l s='Delete' js=1}';
    var labelValidate = '{l s='Validate' js=1}';
    var validate_url = '{$validate_url|addslashes}';
    var carrierlist_url = '{$carrierlist_url|addslashes}';
    var nbr_steps = {$wizard_steps.steps|count};
    var enableAllSteps = {if $enableAllSteps|intval == 1}true{else}false{/if};
    var need_to_validate = '{l s='Please validate the last range before create a new one.' js=1}';
    var delete_range_confirm = '{l s='Are you sure to delete this range ?' js=1}';
    var currency_sign = '{$currency_sign}';
    var PS_WEIGHT_UNIT = '{$PS_WEIGHT_UNIT}';
    var invalid_range = '{l s='This range is not valid' js=1}';
    var overlapping_range = '{l s='Ranges are overlapping' js=1}';
    var range_is_overlapping = '{l s='Ranges are overlapping' js=1}';
    var select_at_least_one_zone = '{l s='Please select at least one zone' js=1}';
    var multistore_enable = '{$multistore_enable}';
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {$logo_content}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div id="carrier_wizard" class="panel swMain">
            <ul class="steps nbr_steps_{$wizard_steps.steps|count}">
            {foreach from=$wizard_steps.steps key=step_nbr item=step}
                <li>
                    <a href="#step-{$step_nbr + 1}">
                        <span class="stepNumber">{$step_nbr + 1}</span>
                        <span class="stepDesc">
                            {$step.title}<br />
                            {if isset($step.desc)}<small>{$step.desc}</small>{/if}
                        </span>
                        <span class="chevron"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
            {foreach from=$wizard_contents.contents key=step_nbr item=content}
                <div id="step-{$step_nbr + 1}" class="step_container">  
                    {$content}
                </div>
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/block}
```

and a part of the RTL css file which is linked to this page is brotught here:

```
#carrier_wizard{position:relative;display:block}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .translatable-field{color:#363A41}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .translatable-field li a{color:#363A41}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .stepContainer{position:relative;display:block;clear:both}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .stepContainer div.content{position:absolute;display:block;width:100%;clear:both}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .stepContainer .StepTitle{display:block;position:relative;clear:both}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard ul.anchor{position:relative;display:block;float:right;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0 0 10px 0;clear:both;width:100%}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard ul.anchor.nbr_steps_4 li{width:25%;float:right}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard ul.anchor.nbr_steps_5 li{width:25%;float:right}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li{position:relative;display:block;overflow:hidden}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a{color:#ccc;height:32px;display:block;position:relative;margin:0 16px 0 0;text-decoration:none;outline-style:none}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a .stepNumber{position:relative;float:right;width:24px;height:32px;margin-right:3px;text-align:center;padding:0 5px;font-size:30px;line-height:32px;color:#fff}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a .stepDesc{position:relative;text-align:right;font-size:13px;height:32px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;line-height:13px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a .chevron{border:16px solid transparent;border-right:14px solid #fff;border-right:0;position:absolute;right:-16px;top:0}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a .chevron:after{border:16px solid transparent;border-right:14px solid #ccc;border-right:0;position:absolute;content:"";right:2px;top:-16px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.disabled{color:#777;background-color:#ccc}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.disabled .chevron:after{border-right:14px solid #ccc}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.selected{color:#F8F8F8;cursor:text;background-color:#363A41}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.selected .chevron:after{border-right:14px solid #363A41}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.done{color:#fff;background-color:#72C279}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard li a.done .chevron:after{border-right:14px solid #72C279}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .loader{display:none}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .msgBox{position:relative;display:none;float:right;margin:4px 0 0 5px;padding:5px;border:1px solid gold;background-color:#ffd;color:#5A5655;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .msgBox .content{padding:0px;float:right}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard #carrier_logo_block{right:10px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_inf td,.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_sup td{background-color:#ccc}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_type{width:220px;text-align:right;font-weight:bold}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_data{width:110px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_sign{width:18px;font-size:20px;text-align:center}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .range_data_new{width:110px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard table#zones_table{width:auto}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .field_error{border-color:#E08F95}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .actionBar{height:30px}.bootstrap 
#carrier_wizard .actionBar a{float:right;margin-right:10px}.bootstrap .size_s{font-size:1.1em}.bootstrap .size_md{font-size:1.3em}.bootstrap .size_l{font-size:1.7em}.bootstrap .size_xl{font-size:2em}.bootstrap .size_xxl{font-size:2.3em}.bootstrap .number-monospace{font-family:"Droid Sans Mono",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;word-spacing:-0.3em;font-weight:200}.bootstrap .color_success{color:#72C279}.bootstrap .color_danger{color:#E08F95}.bootstrap .dash_trend_down{color:#E08F95}.bootstrap .dash_trend_down:before{font-family:FontAwesome;content:"";margin-right:4px}.bootstrap .dash_trend_up{color:#72C279}.bootstrap .dash_trend_up:before{font-family:FontAwesome;content:"";margin-right:4px}.bootstrap .dash_trend_right:before{font-family:FontAwesome;content:"";margin-right:4px}.bootstrap
```

Comment: looks like the `right` css is added as a inline css property. why dont you verify if you have added it or is the plugin adding them

Comment: @dreamweiver As you noticed it is added as inline property, however I cannot track which module or element added this property. I searched in .tpl smarty file or in css files in Prestashop but i could not pinpoint this property.

Comment: hmm in that case, you can use the css specificity `!important`. even though its a bad practice to use it,but now that you have no idea of where its coming from its ok to use it. `right:0px ! important`, place this css property as inline to that tag on load, so that other value will not be updated anytime.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see there is inline CSS and of course no css files related with this element, and no styles in tpl helper for this DIV element, so only 1 way remained to how this style could be applied - using Javascript.

Just check your js files on using `step_container` or `step-` words (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+F in Chrome)